# geocoder.getFromLocation(); Timed out waiting for response from server

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have an Android App launched to market over 6 months, which uses  `geocoder.getFromLocation()` to **"translate"** `latitude` and `longitude` to human readable addresses:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Everything were working fine **until 7 hours ago (2016-01-15 04:00 UTC)**. Worked with Google Support and as per their suggestion, post the problem here to see if anyone have any idea to resolve this problem.

> I've talked with the Maps API's Engineering Team, and it seems that
>   the Android Geocoder uses a different backend than the Geocoding API,
>   which we support, so there is not much we can do from our side right
>   now.

In addition...

- Is the issue happening in all Android devices?  **Yes**
- Can you access the following URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Barcelona
  From a device presenting the issue?   **Yes. We can access it via
  browser in those Android devices.**
- Which version of Android do the devices have? **Android versions ranging from 4.4.4 to 5.1.1**

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue when trying to use the Geocoder and it also started this morning. I've plugged a proxy between my phone and the internet and was able to se a 502 error from Google servers with the message ""The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know." when trying to fetch https://www.google.com/loc/m/api. Maybe you could send this information to them since you're already in touch with support?

Comment: It started working once again for me.

Comment: It's not working for us too. Created following bug with Geocoder team: [https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9153)

Comment: Still not working ...

Comment: We are facing this same issue approximately the same time you started facing it

Comment: Having the same issue. Even on older version - 4.2.2

Comment: Can confirm this. Started aprox 2-3h ago in Europe. N5 and N7 running Marshmallow.

Comment: Berlin here, same problem. N5, N7, N5X (Marshmallows), Galaxy Ace (4.4.2), Galaxy S3 (Lollipop)

Comment: MN, USA, same here. First noticed around 4am GMT. All my apps that use Android geocoder at failing with a timeout.

Comment: It seems to be working again. At least here in Europe.

Comment: For me, it is not working as of today.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for late update here. From the Google's response on 2016-01-15 09:41 PST...

> ...
>
> After reviewing the information you provided, we believe that you may
>   be affected by a known issue.  Here are some details about the issue:
>
> Description: At approximately 11PM PST on 2016-01-14, we began
>   receiving reports that requests made via Android SDK's geocoder are
>   timing. We have identified an outage in our backends which is
>   responsible for the observed errors. Our Eng team is working to
>   address the backend failures.
>
> How to diagnose: Geocode requests using Android's getFromLocation()
>   geocoder method
>   (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)
>   may return a timeout exception.
>
> Workaround: There's no workaround available at this time, but we'll
>   let you know if we learn of one. ...

According to my records, the service has been backed between 2016-01-15 12:00 and 18:00 PST.

And, thanks for Google Support keep me updated before this official response.

Comment: It is still giving me timeout exception but only for first time when I request address from latlong

Comment: I didn't find any fix rather than use http api directly like [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lat,lng&sensor=true](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lat,lng&sensor=true)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Try setting your device's date and time to automatically get it from the network.

I think it's preventing the API from obtaining the security certificate due to incorrect date/time and the API fails. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Mexico, Geocoder working now with normality, check service in your app

Comment: Android Geocoder is terribly unreliable.  IMHO, the class should either be fixed or removed from the platform.  After numerous hours researching Geocoder issues I decided to implement the web api for geocoding.  It never fails unless you go over your api limit.  Instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en_US